# Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560 with FastLED library

Tags: arduino, compilation, led

I started a 3d project of [pixel lamp by Heliox (cults3d link)](https://cults3d.com/fr/mod%C3%A8le-3d/maison/la-lampe-pixel-animee#comments), [french youtube video of the project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94nbqv7Jhlo) and I am having compilation problems and I am a beginner.
I have downloaded the FastLED library and have the file `pixellamp.h`
Also here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1oVRu5Qm_7Lyr85kFy6UF3OYe4PQe78/view) to the original code folder given by the project creator
The error may be because I need to update Arduino IDE.
Ask me anything if their needs more information.

Thanks for any help

PS: I have already sent a message to the creator of the project and waiting for a response

```
In file included from C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\Lampe\Pixelamp\pixelamp\pixelamp.ino:7:0:

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/FastLED.h:14:21: note: #pragma message: FastLED version 3.003.003

 #    pragma message "FastLED version 3.003.003"

                     ^

In file included from C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/fastled_avr.h:6:0,

                 from C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms.h:39,

                 from C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/FastLED.h:52,

                 from C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\Lampe\Pixelamp\pixelamp\pixelamp.ino:7:

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h: In static member function 'static void ClocklessController<DATA_PIN, T1, T2, T3, RGB_ORDER, XTRA0, FLIP, WAIT_TIME>::showRGBInternal(PixelController<RGB_ORDER>&)':

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:409:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 4: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:410:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 3: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:411:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 2: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:425:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 4: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:426:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 3: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:427:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 2: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:444:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 4: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:445:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 3: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:326:24: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'

 #define FL_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough));

                        ^

C:\Users\Mael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FastLED/platforms/avr/clockless_trinket.h:446:55: note: in expansion of macro 'FL_FALLTHROUGH'

      case 2: _D2(0) LO1 _D3(0) HI1 _D1(1) QLO2(b0,0)  FL_FALLTHROUGH

                                                       ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the google results it's because it needs AVR GCC 7.x.x (it's possibly just a bug)

So resolution in Arduino IDE is basically downgrading FastLED library to version 3.3.2 as that one is working and also the latest for Arduino IDE (Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries -> search for: FastLED and select 3.3.2). If it's installed by another way, you should remove that version first.

EDIT: but I've just updated FastLED to 3.3.3 and it's working as well, maybe they fixed it already.

For PlatformIO users there is possibility to change toolchain to version with GCC 7

```
platform_packages =
  ; use GCC AVR 7.3.0+
  toolchain-atmelavr@>=1.70300.0
```

Another way for PlatformIO is forcing older version of FastLED library:

```
lib_deps =
  FastLED@3.3.2
```